# Why is jQuery not imported into the HTML <head>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to coding and following an online HTML and CSS video tutorial.

We are taught that the Bootstrap libraries are generally brought in through the HTML Head or loaded using a gemfile if using a RAILS project.

I noticed today in some code that was furnished that jQuery (necessary for bootstrap JavaScript plugins) were coded at the bottom of the Index.html instead of being referenced through the head of the HTML.

I was curious to understand further. Image attached.

[image]

Comment: Because if it's after all the HTML elements it will load after the initial page has loaded.

Comment: Its a common practice to load Js files into bottom of the page. Reason behind this is to avoid delay in page load. Html pages use to load from top to bottom, so these practice is to avoid loading big js file in beginning. It will help in early page rendering.

Comment: Because otherwise it would block the rendering of the whole page. If you load it at the bottom of your page, your page will be rendered to that point. So the user can already see the page rendered and then jQuery will start loading.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: what are you talking about silly man. throwing your dummy elsewhere. the question was answered to my satisfaction. now jog on

Comment: Does [google](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=Why+is+jQuery++body+end) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put scripts in  tag, the browsers goes for them thereby keeping other stuff on hold until scripts are loaded which users will perceive like slow loading of the page. This is why you should put scripts at the bottom.